# Some general questions about static electricity ( ex : Combing the hair )

Tags: electrostatics, induction

We know , static electricity is built up when i comb my dry hair.

1. what type of charge is gathered in comb & what type of charge in hair ? ( i.e. + or - charge )
2. why would charges would gather ? I mean, human body is a conductor of electricity . then why my hairs would repel each other and become straighten ?
3. I heared that , " Non-conductive materials can't be grounded " . Is that true ? 
   That means , after charges being gathered on comb , even if i connect a wire with the comb and ground it ,the comb would not neutralize ?? am I right ?
4. If I touch the comb with bare hand then would charges flow through my hand , through my body to the ground ?
5. And if I touch the comb in bare hand but disconnected from ground then would charges flow from comb to my body ?
6. If the comb can't be grounded or neutalized .. then would the charges be trapped forever ?? or how can the comb can be charge-neutrilized again ??
7. why the charged comb would attract small papers ? Does any charged body attract neutral bodies ? if they do , why and how ( i mean if it is by electrical induction ?? )

Please answer the question number by number . And please don't give just short answers ( i.e. yes/no ) . I need exact explanations

Comment: What is this now for a post?! Could you make the font any bigger? Every single sentence is filled with question marks, please read the policy of SE before posting! or at least take a look at how others post... All criticisms aside, it's even a duplicate...

Comment: sorry , I'm new here . Would you help me with the policy terms @Phonon

Comment: Why on hold and why so many negative votes, really this is not nice, people. Plus at the time i posted an answer, the question was put on hold.

Comment: well,I don't get it,how my post appears to be off-topic . 
I've gone through this topic , I've googled about these questions , but got no satisfying answer , that's why I've posted here . How can this be against policy ?? Can anyone tell me please .

Comment: About the reason this is on hold as off-topic or homework. i would like to say that whether this is useful or not to broader community depends as much on the answers as on the question itself. It is very possible questions which might appear "naive" (to some "experts") can actually get very nice answers useful for everybody. On the other hand some "elite" questions can get "lousy" answers. This is not a type: "Solve my homework exercise" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is taken from the book "*The evolution of physics*", by A. Einstein,L. Infeld.

It describes exactly this type of static electricity example during the course of how physical ideas about electricity evolved. This is an older popular exposition book, but i think is very good for this question without sacrifising scientific methods.

Initial views on electricity, were that electricity was a kind of fluid consisting of two types of charges i.e positive and negative. In modern terms the negative charges would be **electrons** and positive charges would be **positive ions**.

Most forces and effects one experiences everyday are (mostly) of electromagnetic nature. Like friction, etc..

When materials come into contact or one is rubbed against the other (like the hair-comb example), then depending on the type of materials and their electric distribution (some can expel electrons easier than others whle others can accept electrons easier than others).

Electrons (which carry negative eletric charge) are transfered between the materials, making one material more negative and other more positive (electrically). This creates a static electric potential difference between the two (surfaces of the) materials which has as an effect the attraction or repuslion of the materials.  This is what happens with the hair-comb example.

One should note that it requires specific combs to achieve the effect, while with other types of combs (i.e electrostatic ones), it wil not happen as they are made from such materials (or designed) to not accept ot expel charges so easily.

The previous answer the fist 2 points of the question plus a small introduction to electricity.

Points 4) 5) Yes charges (i.e electrons) will move through the surface and either be absorbed into some molecules or eventually leave your body (e.g grounded).

Point 6) No charges are not trapped for ever, there is change and charges travel all the time betwen surfaces (even with a slower rate), so eventually a comb wil be discharged (albeit it might take longer time).

Point 7) Again this has to do the materials involved and the type of charges accepted or expelled. If one material accepts charges (i.e electrons) and the other expells them, then they will  have between them an attractive electric force.

Comment: @TonmoySarker, welcome, hope it is useful to you :)